using ranksum test within permutation test
I am a bit confused with the definition of the permutation_test function provided by scipy.
the following is what I wrote to calculate the p and null distribution
x = disease['Theta']
y = nodisease['Theta']

def ranksum_statistic(x, y, axis):
    stat, _ = ranksums(x, y, axis = axis, alternative='greater')
    return stat

permutation_test(x, y, ranksum_statistic, permutation_type='independent', 
vectorized=None, n_resamples=9999, batch=None, 
alternative='greater', axis=0, random_state=None)


this will return a p-value drastically different (-log10p = 3) with directly using ranksum test (-log10p = 150) (also, if I run ranksum test multiple times, p-value also changes quite a lot)
I am confused as to which one is more appropriate if I want to compare two different-sized arrays (non-parametric) that came from the same distribution (values are different) since no-disease should already be the null distribution.

You might want to ask this on https://statistics.stackexchange.com .

"also, if I run ranksum test multiple times, p-value also changes quite a lot" Are you talking about permutation_test() or ranksums()? ranksums() should be deterministic. permutation_test is expected to be different each time.

"-log10p = 150" Can you clarify the notation here? Do you mean that you're getting a p-value like 10^-150?

What is your sample size? Why not use the exact option of mannwhitneyu? ranksums uses an asymptotic approximation, and it doesn't use a continuity correction, so mannwhitneyu is essentially always the better choice.

If you have ties and still want an accurate approximation, take a look at https://nbviewer.org/github/scipy/scipy-cookbook/blob/main/ipython/ResamplingAndMonteCarloMethods/resampling_tutorial_2a.ipynb for setting up a permutation version. What you have looks correct from my cell phone, but check against mannwhitneyu with random input. Also, can you post your real data?

In the following, note that ranksums performs essentially the same test as mannwhitneyu. The difference is that ranksums reports a z-score of the statistic rather than the raw integral statistic, and it is incapable of performing a continuity correction and calculating exact p-values as mannwhitneyu can, depending on your parameters. So I'd always suggest using mannwhitneyu, but as requested, I'll answer in terms of ranksums, only using mannwhitneyu as a reference.
Your code is essentially correct. To check, we compare the p-value given by permutation_test against the p-value provided by mannwhitneyu with method='exact'.
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

rng = np.random.default_rng(32590345094235)
x = rng.random(6)
y = rng.random(7)

def ranksum_statistic(x, y, axis):
    stat, _ = stats.ranksums(x, y, axis = axis, alternative='greater')
    return stat

res = stats.permutation_test((x, y), ranksum_statistic, permutation_type='independent', 
                             n_resamples=9999, alternative='greater', axis=0,
                             random_state=rng)
ref = stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y, alternative='greater', method='exact')
np.allclose(res.pvalue, ref.pvalue, rtol=1e-14)

Note that the only meaningful change I made to your code was to pass (x, y) as a tuple rather than as separate arguments. (permutation_test does not accept separate samples as separate arguments; they must be packed in a sequence.)
For these small samples of sizes 6 and 7, we get an exact p-value because n_resamples=9999 is sufficient to perform all binom(6 + 7, 6) = binom(6 + 7, 7) = 1716 permutations. The minimum possible p-value we can get in this case is therefore 1/1716.
If n_resamples is insufficient to perform an exact test, a randomized test is performed, in which case the smallest p-value you can get is 1 / (n_resamples + 1). This occurs when the observed value of the statistic is more extreme than that of every other permutation resample. If n_resamples=9999, that means the smallest p-value you can get from permutation_test is -log10(p) = 3. Yes, the p-value will be stochastic. If you need the stochastic p-value to be reproducible, pass a seeded NumPy Generator explicitly as I have (random_state=rng). Note that in the long run (i.e. many separate data sets), these randomized p-values still control the false-positive rate almost exactly, even if they are only an approximation of the exact p-value for given data. For more information, see Permutation p-values should never be zero.
ranksums always uses an analytical approximation of the null distribution, so it can return smaller p-values. This might be more accurate, but only if your sample sizes are "sufficiently large" such that the asymptotic approximation is valid. To assess whether the tiny p-value you're getting is reasonable, note that the largest possible statistic of the Mann Whitney U test is m*n, where m and n are the sample sizes. If that is the statistic for your observed data, then the exact p-value will be m * n / binom(m + n, m). If ranksums is returning a smaller p-value than that, it is too small.
But again, use mannwhitneyu with method='exact' if you don't have ties and your samples are sufficiently small so that it returns in reasonable time. Note that the exact p-value calculation in SciPy 1.14 is much more efficient than previous versions, so if you can't get an exact p-value in an older version, try upgrading. If you do have ties and/or if your samples are larger than mannwhitneyu with method='exact' can handle, please clarify.
